# Lambda selecting most recent based upon three fields

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need a way to get only the most recent answer which has a specific question id given the following.

The following objects classes:

```
Teams
Store
Employee
Answer
Question
```

The setup:

- Each team has multiple stores.
- Each store has multiple teams.
- Each store also has a collection employees.
- Each employee has a store.
- Some employees have Answers, and these all have multiple responses to the the same question, however I am only concerned with the most recent response to a given question.
- All answers have questions to which they correspond.

I need to run a report that has a count of the most recent answer responses in the database. I only can consider the most recent response from each employee, since employees can change their response every 10 minutes.  I don't care if someone has ever answered "1", what is important to me, is if their most recent response was "1".

If it was I will count them, if not I won't. Also, there are multiple questions.  So I can't just take the most recent answer response, because I will lose the other questions also.

Right now I have the following, which actually counts if ANY of employees have EVER had that answer response.

```
 var answers = _employeeService.GetAll()
                .Where(p => p.Store.Teams.Any(t => t.Team.Id.Equals(teamId)))
                .SelectMany(t => t.Answers)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.Answer.Created)
                .GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    AnswerId = x.Answer.Id,
                    AnswerNumber = x.Answer.Number,
                    AnswerText = x.Answer.Text,
                    QuestionId = x.Answer.Question.Id,
                    QuestionText = x.Answer.Question.Title
                }).Select(x => new AnswerReport()
```

How would I go about filtering that down so I'm not counting people twice? If someone answered 1,2,3,4,5 their answers would be counted five times.

Something like this is what is in my head:

```
        .SelectMany(t => t.Answers)
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.Answer.Created)
        .SelectMostRecent(t => t.Question.Distinct()))  // clearly made up
        .GroupBy(x => new
```

Comment: Made some edits for clarity.

Comment: There should have some `Answer Time` field in your `Answer` so that we can order the `Answers` to get the most recent answers (is that the field `Created`?)?

Comment: @KingKing: Possibly that's Answer.Created?

Comment: It doesn't help that we don't know what the schema looks like. Does `Answer` have anything to link it back to the employee?

Comment: Yes.  Answer is in a clustered index.  It is a Many --> Many relationship.

Answer.Created is the date the answer was created.  I can post the entire schema, but it's huge, would take up a few pages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have employee id as property in the answer entity. Then you can get the most recent answer for each employee and question by grouping on question id and employee id, taking most recent record based on the latest created date for each projected group.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my hacky solution.

```
 //Get all the possible questions in the database, with the count sent to zero
   var allPossible = _assessmentService.GetAll()
     .SelectMany(p => p.Answers).Select(x => new AnswerReport()
          {
              AnswerCount = 0,
              AnswerId = x.Id,
              AnswerNumber = x.Number,
              AnswerText = x.Text,
              QuestionId = x.Question.Id,
              QuestionText = x.Question.Title
          }).ToList();

foreach (var answer in allPossible)
  {     
  /*  Warning: might be too complicated for Linq2Sql */
   answer.AnswerCount = _employeeService.GetAll()
   .Where(e => e.Store.Teams.Any(p => p.Team.Id.Equals(teamId)))
   .Where(e => e.Answers.Any(p => p.Answer.Id.Equals(answer.AnswerId)))
    .Select(a => new
           {
          AnswerInfo = a.Answers
                       .Select(p => new{
                             AnswerId = answer.AnswerId,
                             QuestionId = answer.QuestionId
                             })
                            .FirstOrDefault(ans => 
                             ans.QuestionId.Equals(answer.QuestionId))
            }).ToList()
              //This .ToList() is yucky, but it's a problem with nhibernate
             .Count(a => a.AnswerInfo.AnswerId.Equals(answer.AnswerId));
      }
```